# Android -Some changes to SmsManager - start an activity

Tags: android

I have made some changes to SmsManager. So i would like instead of throw an exception i would like SmsManager to communicate with or start an activity.

Can i do this? If the answer is yes, how can i do it?

Sorry for my english

Comment: check this : http://android10.org/index.php/articlesfullapplications/241-sms-messaging-in-android-send-and-receive

Answer (score 0):

Using SMSManager u can send sms by using `SmsManager.getDefault()` method.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

[Here you find some related to you](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html).
To Launch another activity you can use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);  

public class MessageSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Failed To Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

this.registerReceiver(new MessageSentReceiver() , new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT")); 
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("Phone_No", null, "Text Body", sentPI, null);
```

This way you can get notification of sent message..
If you want notification of message delivery then you can achieve it in the same manner as sent notification.
you can get more info on intent and pending intents from [Developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: How can i catch this intent? These changes and checks which i would like to do, are inside the default source code of android SmsManager and not inside an application.